# Split date range into date range chunks

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a method of splitting a date range into a series of date ranges by chunk size of days.  I am planning on using this to buffer calls to a service which if the date range is too large, the service faults.

This is what I have come up with so far.  It seems to work, but I am not sure if it will exit properly.  This seems like something that has probably been done several times before, but I can't find it.

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
{
    var newStart = start;
    var newEnd = start.AddDays(dayChunkSize);

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(newStart, newEnd);

        if (newEnd == end)
            yield break;

        newStart = newStart.AddDays(dayChunkSize);
        newEnd = (newEnd.AddDays(dayChunkSize) > end ? end : newEnd.AddDays(dayChunkSize));
    }
}
```

I'm looking for improvement suggestions, or "Dude, use this existing function for this!"

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think your code fails when the difference between start and end is smaller than dayChunkSize.
See this:

```
var singleRange = SplitDateRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), dayChunkSize: 15).ToList();
Debug.Assert(singleRange.Count == 1);
```

Proposed solution:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
{
    DateTime chunkEnd;
    while ((chunkEnd = start.AddDays(dayChunkSize)) < end)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(start, chunkEnd);
        start = chunkEnd;
    }
    yield return Tuple.Create(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug, Love the clean look of your solution.

Comment: Very nice answer.  Thank you!
I would add as an additional - if you don't want "overlapping" modify the line "yield return Tuple.Create(start,chunkEnd);" to be "chunkEnd.AddDays(-1)".  This will ensure that the start/end dates for each row do not overlap.

Comment: Does not work for me. I am actually using it inside a C# script embedded in an SSIS (ETL tool) package. I get two errors - Error The body of 'CodeHere.csproj.ScriptMain.SplitDateRange(System.DateTime, System.DateTime, int)' cannot be an iterator block because 'IEnumerable<Tuple<System.DateTime,System.DateTime>>' is not an iterator interface type C:\Users\............blah blah... $$$ AND $$$ The name 'Tuple' does not exist in the current context

Comment: BTW, I added your code after my main method. Also, I was using System.Tuple and i still get the tuple error. I am new to c#, so please bear with me.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This code works only for .NET 4.0 and above. How to make it work for 3.5 and below ?

Comment: public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
        {
            DateTime chunkEnd;
            while ((chunkEnd = start.AddDays(dayChunkSize)) < end)
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(start, chunkEnd);
                start = chunkEnd.AddDays(1);
            }
            yield return Tuple.Create(start, end);
        }

Comment: You can make this more generic by refactoring dayChunkSize to be a TimeSpan interval

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine for me.   I don't really like the idea of `while(true)`
But other solution would be to use enumerable.Range:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable
          .Range(0, (Convert.ToInt32((end - start).TotalDays) / dayChunkSize +1))
          .Select(x => Tuple.Create(start.AddDays(dayChunkSize * (x)), start.AddDays(dayChunkSize * (x + 1)) > end
                                                                       ? end : start.AddDays(dayChunkSize * (x + 1))));
}
```

or also, this will also work:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
{
    var dateCount = (end - start).TotalDays / 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < dateCount; i++)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(start.AddDays(dayChunkSize * i)
                                , start.AddDays(dayChunkSize * (i + 1)) > end 
                                 ? end : start.AddDays(dayChunkSize * (i + 1)));
    }
}
```

I do not have any objects for any of the implementations. They are practically identical.

Comment: I cringed while I was typing the while(true) ;).  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your solution:

- <s>the test `newEnd == end` may never be true, so the `while` could loop forever</s> (I now see that this condition *should* always be triggered, but it wasn't obvious on first reading of the code; the `while(true)` feels a bit dangerous still)
- `AddDays` is called three times for each iteration (minor performance issue)

Here is an alternative:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
{
    DateTime startOfThisPeriod = start;
    while (startOfThisPeriod < end)
    {
        DateTime endOfThisPeriod = startOfThisPeriod.AddDays(dayChunkSize);
        endOfThisPeriod = endOfThisPeriod < end ? endOfThisPeriod : end;
        yield return Tuple.Create(startOfThisPeriod, endOfThisPeriod);
        startOfThisPeriod = endOfThisPeriod;
    }
}
```

Note that this truncates the last period to end on `end` as given in the code in the question. If that's not needed, the second line of the `while` could be omitted, simplifying the method. Also, `startOfThisPeriod` isn't strictly necessary, but I felt that was clearer than reusing `start`.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to accepted answer you could use the short form of tuples:

```
private static IEnumerable<(DateTime, DateTime)> GetDateRange1(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int daysChunkSize)
{
    DateTime markerDate;

    while ((markerDate = startDate.AddDays(daysChunkSize)) < endDate)
    {
        yield return (startDate, markerDate);
        startDate = markerDate;
    }

    yield return (startDate, endDate);
}
```

But I prefer to use named tuples:

```
private static IEnumerable<(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int daysChunkSize)
{
    DateTime markerDate;

    while ((markerDate = startDate.AddDays(daysChunkSize)) < endDate)
    {
        yield return (StartDate: startDate, EndDate: markerDate);
        startDate = markerDate;
    }

    yield return (StartDate: startDate, EndDate: endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution looks good in most cases. If you need to take away overlap on the beginning and the end of each chunk, then this might work better.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
        {
            DateTime chunkEnd;
            while ((chunkEnd = start.AddDays(dayChunkSize-1)) < end)
            {
                yield return (start, chunkEnd);
                start = chunkEnd.AddDays(1);
            }
            yield return (start, end);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many chunks/intervals/periods/parts you want to split your time range into, I've found the following to be helpful

You can use the [DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property to define your intervals, and then create a series of DateTime objects based on your defined interval:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> DivideTimeRangeIntoIntervals(DateTime startTS, DateTime endTS, int numberOfIntervals)
{
    long startTSInTicks = startTS.Ticks;
    long endTsInTicks = endTS.Ticks;
    long tickSpan = endTS.Ticks - startTS.Ticks;
    long tickInterval = tickSpan / numberOfIntervals;

    List<DateTime> listOfDates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (long i = startTSInTicks; i <= endTsInTicks; i += tickInterval)
    {
        listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(i));
    }
    return listOfDates;
}
```

You can convert that `listOfDates` into however you want to represent a timerange (a tuple, a dedicated date range object, etc). You can also modify this function to directly return it in the form you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of corner cases that are unhandled in the answers so far.  And it's not entirely clear how you would want to handle them.  Do you want overlapping start/end of ranges? Is there a minimum range size?  Below is some code that'll handle some of the corner cases, you'll have to think about overlapping especially and possibly push the start/end of ranges by a few seconds or maybe more depending on the data you're returning.

```
    public static IEnumerable<(DateTime start, DateTime end)> PartitionDateRange(DateTime start,
                                                                                DateTime end,
                                                                                int chunkSizeInDays)
    {
        if (start > end)
            yield break;

        if (end - start < TimeSpan.FromDays(chunkSizeInDays))
        {
            yield return (start, end);
            yield break;
        }

        DateTime e = start.AddDays(chunkSizeInDays);

        for (;e < end; e = e.AddDays(chunkSizeInDays))
        {
            yield return (e.AddDays(-chunkSizeInDays), e);
        }

        if (e < end && end - e > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            yield return (e, end);
    }
```

Example call:

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("expected");

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var range in PartitionDateRange(start, end, 2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{range.start} to {range.end}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("start > end");

        start = end + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

        foreach (var range in PartitionDateRange(start, end, 2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{range.start} to {range.end}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("less than partition size");

        start = end - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

        foreach (var range in PartitionDateRange(start, end, 2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{range.start} to {range.end}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hare is an example spliced by month

```
IEnumerable<(DateTime, DateTime)> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int monthChunkSize)
{
    DateTime dateEnd=DateTime.Parse(end.ToString());
    
    for (int i = 0;start.AddMonths(i) < dateEnd; i+=monthChunkSize)
    {
            end = start.AddMonths(i+monthChunkSize);
             start.AddMonths(i);
        
        yield return (start.AddMonths(i), end<dateEnd?end:dateEnd);     
    }
}
```