# Aggregate values at hourly interval using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

I have the following JSON result from API .

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value" : "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:00:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:15:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:30:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "ResultValue": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:45:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "20",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:00:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:15:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:30:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:45:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "30",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 02:00:00"
    }
]
```

**I am trying to show the hourly aggregation using below LINQ query**

```
var aggList = items.GroupBy(u => new { u.ID, u.TimeStamp.Date, u.TimeStamp.Hour })
                            .Select(g => new TestData
                            {
                                ID = g.Key.ID,
                                TimeStamp = g.Key.Date.AddHours(g.Key.Hour),
                                Value = g.Sum(k => k.Value)
                            }).ToList();
```

Which gives result as

```
  ID : 1
    TotalValue : 40
    TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 00:00:00

    ID : 1
    TotalValue : 50
    TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 01:00:00
```

What should be my LINQ query , **If i  want the hourly aggregation to consider from 15th minute instead of 0th minute** .

Like first hour should have aggregation of

```
2019-10-21 00:15:00 - 10
2019-10-21 00:30:00 - 10
2019-10-21 00:45:00 - 10
2019-10-21 01:00:00 - 20
```

**And the expected result should be**

```
        ID : 1
        TotalValue : 50
        TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 00:00:00

        ID : 1
        TotalValue : 60
        TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 01:00:00
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112533/i-want-combine-my-time-slots-as-per-interval-15-30-45-60-and-do-the-additon-o/57114698#57114698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift your `Timestamp` to get the effect. Instead of

```
items.GroupBy(u => new { u.ID, u.TimeStamp.Date, u.TimeStamp.Hour })
```

You shift the time that used for grouping by to be 15 minutes in the past, so everything at the first 15 minutes of the hour go to the earlier hour.

```
items.GroupBy(u => new { u.ID, u.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(-15).Date, u.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(-15).Hour })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var aggList = items.GroupBy(u => new { u.ID, u.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(-15).Date, u.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(-15).Hour })
                            .Select(g => new TestData
                            {
                                ID = g.Key.ID,
                                TimeStamp = g.Key.Date.AddHours(g.Key.Hour),
                                Value = g.Sum(k => k.Value)
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This shift the first 15 minutes of the day away to the 23th hour of that day, while it should actually belong to the day earlier.

Answer (score 0):

*"If i want the hourly aggregation to consider from 15th minute instead of 0th minute"*. You can add 15 minutes to the hour and group them after that.

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<ApiResult>>(File.ReadAllText("../../../data.json"));

var AggValues = result.GroupBy(x => new
{
    x.ID,
    x.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15).Date,
    x.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15).Hour,
    x.Value
}).Select(x => new ApiResult
{
    ID = x.Key.ID,
    TimeStamp = x.Key.Date.AddHours(x.Key.Hour),
    Value = x.Sum(sum => sum.Value)
});

foreach(var i in AggValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ID + " " + i.Value + " " + i.TimeStamp);
}
```

Output:

```
1 30 2019-10-21 00:00:00
1 0 2019-10-21 01:00:00
1 20 2019-10-21 01:00:00
1 20 2019-10-21 01:00:00
1 10 2019-10-21 02:00:00
1 30 2019-10-21 02:00:00
```